# Google Script is outputting image file path instead of image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am working on an app for use on sites that deal with water treatment and waste management.

This app is being developed using appsheet.com

Appsheet creates apps using spreadsheets and stores all data input into the app in these spreadsheets.

I have a script that extracts data from a spreadsheet and applies it to a Google doc template.

The at the end of the template there is a signature section.

Appsheet has a built in signature feature, which stores these signatures as a png file in a subfolder.

In the spreadsheet, the image is kept as a file path, as seen here

[image: Here]

When run, the script interprets this as the text you see and applies it to my template.

I need to be able to read this and apply the image, not the file path.

I have tried using some of the various image classes explained on the Apps Script Reference, none of which have worked for me.

```
function chooseRowMethod(templateId){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
 var values = dataRange.getValues();
 var data = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 11, 18).getValues();//starting with row 2 and column 1 as our upper-left most column, get values from cells from 1 row down, and 15 columns along - hence (2,1,1,15)
 var docTitle = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 11, 1).getValues();//this is grabbing the data in field B2
 var docTitleTagNumber = sheet.getRange(2, 3, 11, 1).getValues();
 var today = new Date();
 var dd = today.getDate();
 var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

 for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++){
     if(values[i][j] == response){
       Logger.log(i);
       var row = data[i - 1];
       var docId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
       var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
       var body = doc.getActiveSection();
       body.replaceText("%SITEID%", row[0]);
       ...
       body.replaceText("%SIGNED%", row[16]);
       doc.saveAndClose();

       var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
       var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16wRGBVdV0OZ5YfKhqEQSFMsux-ekGCCa");
       newFolder.addFile(file); 
       var newDocTitle = docTitle[i - 1][0];
       var newDocTagNumber = docTitleTagNumber[i - 1][0];

       doc.setName(newDocTitle + " " + newDocTagNumber + " " + today);
     }
   }
 } 
}
```

I am aware that the `body.replaceText()` line does exactly as it says.  I have tried using `body.setImage()`, but this also failed to get any results.

The expect result is picture that is taken from its folder and applied to the template using the file path that is given in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time on other parts of this project, I have come back to this problem and found a solution using the following code.

```
var signature = row[17];
        var sign = signature.substring(signature.indexOf("/") + 1);

        var sigFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16C0DR-R5rJ4f5_2T1f-ZZIxoXQPKvh5C");
        var files = sigFolder.getFilesByName(sign);
        var n = 0;
        var file;

        while(files.hasNext()){
          file = files.next();
          n++;
        } if(n>1){
          SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alers('there is more than one file with this name' + sign);
        }
        var sigElectInstaller = "%SIGNELECTINSTALL%";
        var targetRange = body.findText(sigElectInstaller); // Finding the range we need to focus on
        var paragraph = targetRange.getElement().getParent().asParagraph(); // Getting the Paragraph of the target
        paragraph.insertInlineImage(1, file.getBlob());// As there are only one element in this case you want to  insert at index 1 so it will appear after the text // Notice the .getBlob()
        paragraph.replaceText(sigElectInstaller, ""); // Remove the placeholder
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

You want to insert image from Google Drive to Google Docs document body.

**Solution**

Use the `InlineImage` element (class) and corresponding `appendImage()` or `insertImage()` methods. This is done in three simple steps:

1. Access your image file (e.g. `DriveApp.getFileById()` or similar, it's up to you);
2. Get file data as `Blob` class instance via `getBlob()` method;
3. invoke `appendImage()` or `insertImage()` with blob as argument (note that `insertImage()` requires child element index as its first argument).

**Sample**

```
function insertImage() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('TEST');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var image = DriveApp.getFileById('yourIdHere').getBlob();
  var inline = body.appendImage(image);
}
```

**Reference**

1. `insertImage()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertImage(Integer,InlineImage));
2. `appendImage()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendimageimage);
3. `getBlob()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getBlob());

Comment: Hi Ciaran! Then make the id dynamic :) This is just a sample, you could, for example, extract image name from `row[16]` value (I assume this is where your link is stored, right?), use `DriveApp`'s method `getFilesByName(name)` to get file iterator, then iterate (if names are unique, you won't even need to make more than one cycle) and get id of the file via `getId()`